# change this style attribute from class element on click

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const expandIt = document.querySelectorAll('.k-grid')
.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => {
  el.classList.add('pressed') // This wont work getting HTML obj etc in console
  console.log('pressed' + el)
  $(this).css({'white-space':'normal'}); // this works in console 
}))
```

Above is what I have; I am simply trying to set white space to normal on current clicked element. I think using this would work - classList doesn't seem to be working I guess from how/when dynamic elems are injected. I am looking for plain JS, or ideally ES6.

Comment: If your HTML is like Chris' answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258765/573719 I don't see how yours wouldn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `event` as a function parameter and set `el = event.target`

```js
const expandIt = document.querySelectorAll('.k-grid')
  .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const el = event.target;
    el.classList.add('pressed') // This will work getting HTML obj etc in console
    console.log('pressed' + el);
  }))
```

```css
.k-grid {padding: 1em; float: left;}
.pressed {font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<div class="k-grid">Hello</div>
<div class="k-grid">Hello</div>
<div class="k-grid">Hello</div>
```

**[HTML DOM addEventListener() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp)**

> *function*
>
> Required. Specifies the function to run when the event occurs.
>
> When the event occurs, **an event object is passed to the function as
>   the first parameter**. The type of the event object depends on the
>   specified event. For example, the "click" event belongs to the
>   MouseEvent object.
>
> <sup>Bold emphasis mine</sup>